# Offline Python Speech Recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am creating a project that must respond to voice commands. I want this to work offline and I need it to be fast. I have tried PocketSphinx but it is not accurate enough. I will say, "hello", and in a quiet room it will display "mello" or "chello" my mic is good. What should I do? If I try to recognize it with google recognition then I get the perfect results. But my internet is slow and it takes forever. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try snowboy.kitt.ai it is a wake word engine so you can have it recognize commands like "turn on the lights" or "hey Jarvis"